# Loading two dlls which are themselves statically linked with different version of a library causes a crash when these both are loaded in a executable

Tags: windows, dynamic, dll, static, linker

We have two dlls say A and B. Both use different versions of library C which is linked statically into them.
Now when we load these dlls in a executable, and use their functionality the program crashes.

Can someone explain the reason behind this and how to fix it?
We could see this issue in XP only and it works fine in Windows 7 (somehow)

Comment: It doesn't really matter the version of the CRT if: it's statically linked and that DLLs does not interop. But if you pass/use CRT structures from A to B then you may (I should say you will) have problems. Simply do not mix them or use same version, no option if you want to be safe. Implementation details (and a private field in a struct is an impl. detail) may change from one version to the other.

Comment: In our case the dlls does not interop and they have lib C statically linked (different versions) but still it is crashing. If we use only one of these dlls it works well?   When we load the dlls in the program memory, won't same methods with different signatures or same signatures conflict because they are not in different namespace ?

Comment: No, each method is loaded at a different address. Formal speaking they're more or less different methods (a function that uses strcmp() in A.dll won't call strcmp() "imported" in B.dll). They doesn't crash in this way but CRT may have subtles behaviors. Moreover it could simply be a bug in the program itself. What compilers are you using?

Comment: In addition to not being able to pass structures between A and B, there are any number of other things that could be going wrong.  They might both be trying to create an event object with the same name, just for example.  Without the source code to (both versions of) library C there's really no way to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program crashes because different versions of the C DLL have different type definitions which conflict with each other. If you have certain fields that don't exist in one version and exist in another, then depending on the type of the DLL, you'll get 2 different scenarios. Managed will fail to bind and will tell you that. Unmanaged will corrupt memory and you will get some nasty error elsewhere unexpectedly.

You're seeing different behavior between OSes probably because XP does its memory management differently than 7 (leading me to believe it's unmanaged DLLs), but it's tough to tell.

Comment: You are right, its unmanaged dlls only. But is there a way such that our program can load both these dlls together and these dlls still statically bind to different versions of lib C

Comment: You should be able to do that, as long as you don't try passing updated data structures that are created inside A (and/or its version of C) to B and vice-versa.

Comment: Also, if I was you, I would avoid having to use 2 versions of the same DLL (the C) inside a single process. Unmanaged coding is difficult as it is, without introducing wild cards like 2 versions running side by side inside a process.